# Media queries in Css with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a real tough time figuring out why my media queries aren't working whenever I include bootstrap.css. When I don't include bootstrap.css the media queries work perfectly but as soon as I link, it stops responding. Here's my html and css code. Thank you!!!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>


 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Responsive Exps</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="untitled.css">



 <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>

 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<h1>This is awesome that you can have responsive sites</h1>

 </body>
 </html>
```

-----CSS------

```
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {

body{
    background-color: darkblue;
    font-size: 40px;
   }

  }


  @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

body{
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
 }

} 


 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

body{
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size: 20px;
   }

  }


 @media (max-width: 767px) {

body{
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 10px;
    }

   }


@media (max-width: 480px) {

body{
background-color: black;
   }  


   }
```

Comment: Are you placing your CSS after Bootstraps CSS because your example works as expected with Bootstraps CSS. More information on how you're doing this would be helpful along with a working example that demonstrates the problem. [mcve].

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was placing the bootstrap.css file below my untitled.css file. But now it's working, I am so sorry.